# How do I paginate using swift and firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, pagination, swift4.1

I am working on an iOS app which has features similar to Instagram. I have successfully done pagination on my profile page but constantly failing to get the right result in my home feed.

Goal - to fetch the posts in chronological order by date. Latest one should come first. Posts are from the people I follow. Fetching 3 first and then another 3 when scrolled down.

Sample firebase real-time database structure.

Users table

```
users
 -uid
  -name
  -emailID
```

posts table

```
posts
 -uid
   -pid
    -title
    -date
   -pid2
    -title
    -date
```

Controller.swift

I get the all the uids of the particular user is following 
and then I try to fetch posts from those uids

```
fileprivate func fetchPosts() {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    Database.fetchUserWithUID(uid: uid) { (user) in

        self.fetchPostsWithUser(user: user)

    }
}
```

---

```
fileprivate func fetchPostsWithUser(user: User) {
    let uid = user.uid

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid)

    var query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "creationDate")

    if posts.count > 0 {
        let value = posts.last?.creationDate.timeIntervalSince1970
        query = query.queryEnding(atValue: value)
    }

    query.queryLimited(toLast: 3).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard var allObjects = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }

        allObjects.reverse()

        print("coint is , ", allObjects.count)
        if allObjects.count < 2 {
            self.isFinishedPaging = true
        } else {
            self.isFinishedPaging = false
        }
        if self.posts.count > 0 && allObjects.count > 0 {
            allObjects.removeFirst()
        }

        allObjects.forEach({ (snapshot) in
            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            var post = Post(user: user, dictionary: dictionary)

            post.id = snapshot.key

            self.posts.append(post)
        })


        self.collectionView?.reloadData()


    }) { (err) in
        print(err)
    }

}
```

---

extension

```
extension Database {

    static func fetchUserWithUID(uid: String, completion: @escaping (User) -> ()) {
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let userDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            let user = User(uid: uid, dictionary: userDictionary)
            completion(user)


        }) { (err) in
            print("Failed to fetch user for posts:", err)
        }
    }
```

This code works but weirdly. I don't get the posts in right order. It is always giving me an output of randomly ordered posts.

What should I do?

Comment: I am not seeing anything really wrong with this code, and running it in a test app works consistently and does what it's supposed to in the correct order. However, I don't know how your creationDate string is stored in Firebase. It may also be easier instead of reversing allobjects to build an array, simply clearing the post array, then iterate over the snapshot.children and insert each new post at position 0. The will naturally put the most recent post at the top. Also, you need to ensure every posts node contains a *creationDate* child as if not, it won't sort properly.

Answer (score 1):

1). Fetch first 5 data from firebase Here my Table name is "Tweets"

```
    let FetchtweetRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    FetchtweetRef.child("Tweets").queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toLast: 5).observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (tweets) in

        for  tweet in tweets.children{
            let newTweet = Tweet(snaspshot: tweet as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            // Store object in Array
        }

        FetchtweetRef.child("Tweets").removeAllObservers()
    })
```

2). After Fetch Next 5 data on your tableview scrolling.

```
    // Here find last object key from array.
    let key = self.tweetArray[self.tweetArray.count].key

    let FetchtweetRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    FetchtweetRef.child("Tweets").queryOrderedByKey().queryEnding(atValue: key).queryLimited(toLast: 6).observe(.value, with: {(tweets) in

        for  tweet in tweets.children {
            let newTweet = Tweet(snaspshot: tweet as! FIRDataSnapshot)
           // Stored object in Array
        }
        FetchtweetRef.child("Tweets").removeAllObservers()
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the posts in a random order is because `observeSingleEvent(of: )` fetches data from the database as first come first serve type of basis. So in the Firebase UI it may be alphabetically based on creation, but that doesn't mean it'll show up in the view when fetched. You'll have to use `queryOrderedByKey`) or (`queryOrderedByValue`) and sort it by the key/value (if you create posts by `childByAutoID` it will automatically be from oldest (on top) to newest when created.

Comment: Okay. Trying your solution. Thank you!

Comment: @Api42 The OP has ordering clearly defined in code *ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "creationDate")* so that will maintain the date order within the firebase snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the follow lines in between self.posts.append and reloadData will solve your issue.

```
                self.posts.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
                    return p1.creationDate.compare(p2.creationDate) == .orderedDescending })
```